# Overloading operators and writing manipulators?

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

Ok, I can't get this code work:
I want to concatenate my custom manipulators.
so they will be called like `cout << endl` is called.
for example I want this:

```
   emit << event1 << event2 << event3;
```

here is my code:

```
class Emit
{
public:
                // ...
    const void operator<<(const Event& _event) const;
}const emit; // note this global

inline const void Emit::operator<<(const Event& _event) const
{
    Start(_event);
}


class Event 
{
               // ...
         const Event& Event::operator<<(const Event& _event) const;
};

inline const Event& Event::operator<<(const Event& _event) const
{
    return _event;
}
```

However I cant call this:

```
 emit << event1 << event2 << event3;
```

I'm eather receiving compile time error, link time errors and what ever I change in my code I get coresponding error no success.

for example this one:

> Error 1   error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a
>   right-hand operand of type 'const EventHandling::Event' (or there is
>   no acceptable conversion) c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio
>   2010\projects\cppsystem\eventhandling\test.h  18

thanks alot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those operators are called from left to right. As such, the first call (`emit << event1`) must return a reference to `Emit`:

```
class Emit
{
public:
    // ...
    Emit const& operator<<(const Event& _event) const;
}const emit; // note this global

Emit const& Emit::operator<<(const Event& _event) const
{
    Start(_event);
    return *this;
}
```

And now you don't need to overload `operator<<` in your `Event` class anymore.

Comment: ahahah :D I get it now, thanks alot Xeo, you just saved my keyboard's life! your code work like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

If your manipulators don't contain any data you can actually just write a function. For example, `std::endl` is implemented roughly like this (it needs to cope with wide streams as well and thus does some magic to arrange for characters be converted):

```
std::ostream& endl(std::ostream& out) {
    (out << '\n').flush();
    return out;
}
```

If your manipulators have some data you need to store the data in a suitable object and then just create a normal output operator for this class, for example `std::setw()` could be implemented like this (again, ignoring that the streams are actually templates):

```
struct std::setw {
    setw(int size): size_(size) {}
    int size_;
};
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, std::setw const& object) {
    out.width(object.size_);
    return out;
}
```

You can implement output operators as a member because you don't control the left side of the `operator<<()`: this is where the stream object sits. If you were implementing `std::ostream` you could implement these members (well, actually, the standard mandates that certain output operators are members of `std::ostream`).

Comment: Oh, thanks alot for that valuable info, vote+, but I've allready accepted the answer from Xeo since he posted in a minit. thanks again!!